# Getting link active when user is in nested router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to give the specific link "Event" an active class when visiting a nested view link.
For example `/event/TER63D/tickets` but that doesn't seem to work with the standard vue router. I've found some solutions but these seem to be for older versions or simply don't work.

App Nav Template

```html
<template>
  <nav>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/event">Event</router-link> (I want this to have the class "active" when visiting /event/TER63D/tickets) 
  </nav>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

Router

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
  },
  {
    path: "/event/:id",
    name: "eventlist",
    component: EventView,
    children: [
      {
        path: "tickets",
        component: TicketsView,
      },
      {
        path: "shop",
        component: ShopView,
      },
    ],
    props: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/404",
    name: "404",
    component: () => import("../views/NotFoundView.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)", // Unrecognized path automatically matches 404
    redirect: "/404",
  },
];
```

**`UPDATE`**

I get it to work the way I want to, but i dont know if its the right way. I am very new to VueJs.

This is the updated code.

App Nav Template

```html
<template>
  <nav>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
    <router-link :class="currentlyActive[0] === 'event' ? 'router-link-exact-active' : ''" to="/event">Event</router-link> (I want this to have the class "active" when visiting /event/TER63D/tickets) 
  </nav>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AppView",
  data() {
    return {
      currentlyActive: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    $route(to) {
      this.currentlyActive = to.name.split(".");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Router

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
  },
  {
    path: "/event/:id",
    name: "event",
    component: EventView,
    children: [
      {
        path: "tickets",
        component: TicketsView,
        name: "event.tickets",
      },
      {
        path: "shop",
        component: ShopView,
        name: "event.shop",
      },
    ],
    props: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/404",
    name: "404",
    component: () => import("../views/NotFoundView.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)", // Unrecognized path automatically matches 404
    redirect: "/404",
  },
];
```

Comment: Can't you give every route a name, and when visiting that route, compare the current route name with your desired route and if true, assign the class you want? Wait, you can compare the paths as well.

Comment: @NehaSoni I updated the code/topic, but i dont know if its the right way. But it works. You can see the code in my question.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not a bad way. However, I'll find if any other way is recommendable to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have event path and page in this structure.

you can add event route like bottom.

Router

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
  },
   {
      path: '/event',
      redirect: "/404", // or component: EventList,
      children: [
        {
          path: ":id",
          name: "eventlist",
          component: EventView,
          children: [
            {
              path: "tickets",
              component: TicketsView,
            },
            {
              path: "shop",
              component: ShopView,
            },
          ],
          props: true,
        },
      ]
    },
  {
    path: "/404",
    name: "404",
    component: () => import("../views/NotFoundView.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)", // Unrecognized path automatically matches 404
    redirect: "/404",
  },
];
```

App Nav Template

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/event">Event</router-link> (I want this to have the class "active" when visiting /event/TER63D/tickets) 
  </nav>
  <router-view />
</template>
```